# Does not include images in the body of the email garethp/php-ews

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to bring in the information that is in the body of the email, including some images that are normally pasted in the body of the email. But it doesn't bring me these images that are embedded in the body. I am using the garethp/php-ews library for this.

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use garethp\ews\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\MailAPI;

$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword('server', 'username', 'password');

$items = $api->getMailItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item instanceof Type\MessageType) {
        $emailId = $item->getItemId()->getId();
        $subject = $item->getSubject();
        echo "EmailId: " . $emailId . "<br>";
        echo "Subject: " . $subject . "<br>";
        $body = $api->getItem($item->getItemId());
        $bodyHtml = $body->getBody();
        echo "Body: " . $bodyHtml . "<br>";
    }
}
```

With the previous code it brings me the body of the email, but not the images that are embedded. This is how it shows them in the code but it does not bring any image.

```
<img width="260" height="151" id="x_Imagen_x0020_1" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" src="cid:image001.png@01DA1166.EB5E1980">
```

Would there be a way to get it all at once in base64? Something in the configuration or getting this image embedded so that it shows it on another page apart from the email?

Answer (score 0):

`cid` is just a **content ID** - i.e. a key that has a base64 value for your image. Attachments should be received by a separate request from
[API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/resources/itemattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0) . I think this example will help you [Example](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/blob/master/examples/mail/gettingEmailAttachments.php)

then try:

```php
public function cidBody(string $body = '', array $attachments = [])
{
    if (empty($body) || count($attachments) === 0) {
        return $body;
    }

    $inlineAttachments = Arr::where($attachments, function ($attachment) {
        return ($attachment['isInline'] ?? false) && isset($attachment['contentId']);
    });

    $contentIds = Arr::pluck($inlineAttachments, 'contentBytes', 'contentId');

    return preg_replace_callback("~cid:([\w_\d\-\.]+)~", function (array $matches) use ($contentIds) {

        if (isset($matches[1]) && key_exists($matches[1], $contentIds)) {
            return 'data:image/png;base64,' . $contentIds[$matches[1]];
        }

        return $matches[0];
    }, $body);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what should I send in the $attachments variable, additionally where the Arr class comes from?

Comment: `$attacments` is the response from the API. (i.e. the media for the message). I attached the function for an example of how to replace `cid` with the value of the image from your `<img src="cid:image001.png@01DA1166.EB5E1980">`.

Comment: `Arr` is just part of the array handling [package](https://github.com/laravel/helpers). You can just replace it with your own function. `Arr::where = array_search`. `Arr::pluck = array_map`. Just form an array where the key is `cid` and the value is the image (base64). The `preg_replace_callback` searches for the cid and changes it to a image